# Seeing MKAnnotation Coordinates During Drag

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to be able to track the coordinates of my `MKAnnotation` as I drag it. Currently, I am only getting the coordinates as the drag begins.

I have tried implementing a custom `MKAnnotationView` subclass with `touchesMoved`, however this appears not to work. (As suggested here: [Obtaining MKAnnotation's coordinate while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626641/obtaining-mkannotations-coordinate-while-dragging).)

By receiving the new coordinates as I drag my annotation, I will in turn be able to update my polygon shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the coordinates from `MKAnnotationView`.

When your view is dragged.The following delegate gets called.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
```

In that you can use :

```
if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [_polyMapView convertPoint:view.center toCoordinateFromView:view.superview];
}
```

Here `_polyMapView` would be your mapView and `view` would be your annotation view.This would get you the current coordinates of the Annotation.