# MKAnnotation Coordinates during Drag SWIFT

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I am trying to redraw polylines on a mapView to and from an MKAnnotation, however it only redraws once I drop the pin, and I want the lines to continue to redraw even as the pin is being dragged.

I have seen this question, in Objective C, [Seeing MKAnnotation Coordinates During Drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048583/seeing-mkannotation-coordinates-during-drag) ,  however, not sure how to do something similar in swift.

here is where I create the pin, it is a custom mkAnnotation.

```
         self.holeCenterCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(holeX, holeY)
        self.centerpin.coordinate = self.holeCenterCoordinates
        self.centerpin.draggable = true
        self.centerpin.imageName = "mapDragCircle.png"
        self.holeMap.addAnnotation(self.centerpin)
    })
```

and this is where I add the lines:

```
    let userToCenter = [self.centerpin.coordinate, manager.location?.coordinate] as! [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
    let centerToGreen = [greenCenter2D, self.centerpin.coordinate]


    let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: userToCenter, count: userToCenter.count)
    let polyline2 = MKPolyline(coordinates: centerToGreen, count: centerToGreen.count)
        holeMap.add(polyline2)
    let overlays = self.holeMap.overlays
    holeMap.removeOverlays(overlays)
    holeMap.add(polyline)
    holeMap.add(polyline2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are dragging pin to another location , then fetch latitude and longitude for that new pin location and then first clear old polylines and draw new polylines using new pin location.

Comment: That's what my current code does, however it redraws once the pin is dropped. I want it to redraw as it's being moved.

Comment: Please go througn this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344993/mkmapkit-draggable-annotation-and-drawing-polygons

Comment: this draws lines, which I already have, and sets pins. my app can already drag a pin and update the overlay once it has landed. the problem is that it won't update when the annotation is 'in transit' so to speak. while it is being dragged to it's new position.